# setting up ODE (open dynamics engine) to work in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, compilation, ode-library

I am trying to set up the ODE source code to work in visual studio. I have followed to instructions given in [this link](http://opende.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Manual_%28Install_and_Use%29#Building_with_Premake), which say to cd to the build directory and run the commnad `premake4 vs2008`.
that runs fine, and indeed, all the vs2008 files are created. But when I try to compile the project, I get an error saying that `ode.dll` cannot be found - should it be downloaded\installed separately or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

you should take a look a this link below 
http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/arsproject/index.php?title=Main_Page#Visual_Studio

go to the section (middle of the page) Open Dynamic Engine (ODE)
Installation Steps for Windows.

I followed these steps and the installation works fine. In the ODE lib folder, do you have 2 folders 
with name such as DebugDoubleDll or ReleaseDoubleDll? if you have compiled in double precision. 
If yes, you should have a library named ode_doubled.lib in the ODE lib folder.

Did you try to run the demo executable to test your installation?

Last thing, did you include in your PATH environment variable the lib folder (where the libraries are located), if no, it's probably the reason why you have this error message.

Comment: Cannot find a tutorial for VS in that link anymore